# How to enable Intellisense in Html Helper with MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, html-helper

I basically followed this article:  http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/

My HtmlHelper class is located in the root directory of my MVC project:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcHtmlHelpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString Hello(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

If I reference it in a view: `@using MvcHtmlHelpers;` I get intellisense and view code validates fine (no red underlines).

If I don't reference it in a View, but reference it in either one or both of the 2 web.config files, I don't get intellisense and `@Html.Hello()` is now red underlined.

Now the best part is that when I run, it renders perfectly fine even if I don't have it referenced anywhere at all.  Ideally, I would like to reference it once in the `web.config` and get Intellisense in a view without referencing it in that view.

UPDATE:  I guess something got cached somewhere.  It does NOT render when it's not referenced anywhere.  I'm sorry.  I would still like to get Intellisense and validation in a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Razor view engine you need to reference it in `~/Views/web.config` and not in `~/web.config`:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MvcHtmlHelpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Then recompile, close and reopen the Razor view and if it is your lucky day you might even get Intellisense. If not you may curse at Microsoft.

Comment: @Dimskiy, if you add the correct namespace to the `~/Views/web.config` your application will at least work when you run it. As far as Intellisense is concerned, as I said in my answer, it will depend on whether it's your lucky day or not. Normally it works, but ...

Comment: Ha! So the closing and reopening of VS did it!  I was about to start banging my head on the keyboard.  Thanks a lot!  I guess after all, it is my lucky day ;)